# Error when setting value in angular module when data is not available

Tags: javascript, angularjs, client-server, client-side

I try to pass user's value to angular code. In order do do that on the server side I pass user's data with res.render and on client side I set the value:

```
<script>
   angular.module('UserModule', []).value('user', {req.user|js|s});
</script>
```

Unfortunately, when user is not present it is rendered as:

```
angular.module('UserModule', []).value('user', );
```

and it results in a an error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
```

Any idea how I could avoid this error when user data is not present?

Comment: Remove the comma angular.module('UserModule', []).value('user');

Comment: You could firstly set the `req.user = {}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written in first comment, make sure that `req.user` is an empty object (`{}`) if no data is available. BTW I saw the following pattern to inject data into the angular app in a Google talk and I find it quite useful:

1. Assign your data in your HTML:

   ```
   <script>
     window.user = {req.user|js|s};
   </script>
   ```
2. Provide the data in config phase as a constant:

   ```
   angular.module('UserModule', []).
     config(function(){
       $provide.constant('user', angular.copy(window.user));
     })
   ```